# Reasons for objects becoming null in Extended Application class

Tags: java, android

In my android application, I have extended Application class. I am having some meta data which I do not want to re-initialize again and again. I initialize them in Application class and then use them.

```
private SampleSettings getSettings(){
     return sampleSettings;
}


 public class SampleApplication extends Application {

    public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    sampleSettings = getSettingsFromDB();
    }

}
```

Here getSettings returns null in some cases when accessed in application using applicationContext.

Sometime I am getting null pointer exception for such properties. I have seen when the app goes to background it occurs but not frequently.

My understanding is that those values should not become as long as application is started.

What am I missing which is causing them to become null?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but your question looks like one from a newbie who never bothered to read about [mcve]; or visited the [help] in general to understand how to ask "code not working questions".

Answer (score 3):

Your process does not live forever. When you are not in the foreground, [your process may be terminated at any time by Android, to free up system RAM for other apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

A custom `Application` object, or any `static` fields, are only for caching and other in-flight data. Your app needs to be able to start up, from any activity, lazy-initializing all of that as needed.

Comment: Thank for the info. Can you suggest a code sample which can help in lazy initializing an activity. Also is there any way we can simulate this while testing?

Comment: I think I am facing this http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/ :D